# How to remove hours, minutes, seconds and UTC offset from pandas date column? I'm running with streamlit and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, streamlit

How to remove T00:00:00+05:30 after year, month and date values in pandas? I tried converting the column into datetime but also it's showing the same results, I'm using pandas in streamlit. I tried the below code

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

The output is same as below :

```
Date
2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-03T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-03T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-04T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-04T00:00:00+05:30
2019-07-05T00:00:00+05:30
```

Can anyone help me how to remove T00:00:00+05:30 from the above rows?

Comment: if you don't need datetime functionality, just split the strings, don't call pd.to_datetime. Ex: `pd.Series(["2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30"]).str.split('T').str[0]`

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep only the date part.

Convert date strings to datetime

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns={'date'},
    data=["2019-07-01T02:00:00+05:30", "2019-07-02T01:00:00+05:30"]
)
                        date
0  2019-07-01T02:00:00+05:30
1  2019-07-02T01:00:00+05:30
2  2019-07-03T03:00:00+05:30

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

                       date
0 2019-07-01 02:00:00+05:30
1 2019-07-02 01:00:00+05:30
```

Remove the timezone

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(None)

                 date
0 2019-07-01 02:00:00
1 2019-07-02 01:00:00
```

Keep the date only

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date

0    2019-07-01
1    2019-07-02
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with `apply` to Python dates or string changes. The former will leave you with an object type column and the latter is slow. Just round to the day frequency using the library function.

```
>>> pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2000-01-05 12:01')]).dt.round('D')
0   2000-01-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you have a timezone aware timestamp, convert to UTC with no time zone then round:

```
>>> pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30')]).dt.tz_convert(None) \
        .dt.round('D')
0   2019-07-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas doesn't have a builtin conversion to `datetime.date`, but you could use `.apply` to achieve this if you want to have `date` objects instead of string:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": [
        "2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-02T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-03T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-03T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-04T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-04T00:00:00+05:30",
        "2019-07-05T00:00:00+05:30"]})

df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(x).date())
print(df)
```